# Not sure what is wrong with my code

Tags: java, android

Hey I was getting back into android programming, and was doing the developer.google.com tutorial and I dont know what is wrong here...

In the "public void sendMessage(View view) {" line, i get the error ';' expected.

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
package com.apps.graham.myfirstapp;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.apps.graham.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_my, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //Called when the user clicks the send button next to the text field.
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) return true;
        {
        public void sendMessage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewByID(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are creating a method inside another method. This is not right

Comment: Plus you have an If with `;` yet still have brackets afterwards?

Comment: @Graham Mackintosh Do you want to move to another screen after an item is tapped in the main screen's menu?

Comment: You are creating a method inside another method. This is  wrong way

Answer (score 1):

Tricks:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //Called when the user clicks the send button next to the text field.
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        //sendMessage(your-view); here, if you want to do that.
        return true;
    }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

And your new method can't be defined inside another method:

```
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewByID(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```